Cannot authenticate to my newly created strimzi kafka cluster
I have a brand new strimzi cluster setup in AWS EKS that I am trying to test authentication via a python script to access the newly created topic using the newly created kafka user.
Below are my manifests, and the python script. Please advise.
Kafka Node pools and Cluster
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaNodePool
metadata:
  name: kraft-controller
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 3
  roles:
    - controller
  storage:
    type: jbod
    volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 10Gi
        kraftMetadata: shared
        deleteClaim: false
        class: test-platform-team-sc
---

apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaNodePool
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 3
  roles:
    - broker
  storage:
    type: jbod
    volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 10Gi
        kraftMetadata: shared
        deleteClaim: false
        class: test-platform-team-sc

---

apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
  annotations:
    strimzi.io/node-pools: enabled
    strimzi.io/kraft: enabled
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.8.0
    metadataVersion: 3.8-IV0
    authorization:
        type: simple
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 3
      min.insync.replicas: 2
  entityOperator:
    # ...
    topicOperator:
      watchedNamespace: strimzi-kafka
      reconciliationIntervalMs: 60000
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 500Mi
        limits:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 500Mi
    # ...
    userOperator:
      watchedNamespace: strimzi-kafka
      reconciliationIntervalMs: 60000
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 500Mi
        limits:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 500Mi

---


Kafka Topics
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaTopic
metadata:
  name: flink-input
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster
spec:
  partitions: 10
  replicas: 2

apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaTopic
metadata:
  name: flink-output
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster
spec:
  partitions: 10
  replicas: 2

Kafka User
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaUser
metadata:
  name: flink
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster
spec:
  authentication:
    type: scram-sha-512
  authorization:
    type: simple
    acls:
      # Example consumer Acls for topic my-topic using consumer group my-group
      - resource:
          type: topic
          name: flink-input
          patternType: literal
        operations:
          - Create
          - Describe
          - Write
          - Read
        host: "*"
      - resource:
          type: group
          name: my-group
          patternType: literal
        operations:
          - Read
        host: "*"
      # Example Producer Acls for topic my-topic
      - resource:
          type: topic
          name: flink-output
          patternType: literal
        operations:
          - Create
          - Describe
          - Write
          - Read
        host: "*"


Python Script
import logging
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

# Enable logging for kafka-python
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Configuration
BROKER = "AWSELBFQDN:9092"
TOPIC = "flink-input"
USERNAME = "flink"
PASSWORD = "DecodedSecretPassword"

try:
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        TOPIC,
        bootstrap_servers=[BROKER],
        security_protocol="SASL_PLAINTEXT",
        sasl_mechanism="PLAIN",
        sasl_plain_username=USERNAME,
        sasl_plain_password=PASSWORD,
        group_id="my-group",
        auto_offset_reset="earliest",
        consumer_timeout_ms=10000
    )

    print("Successfully connected to Kafka broker.")
    print(f"Listening to topic: {TOPIC}")
    for message in consumer:
        print(f"Received message: {message.value.decode('utf-8')}")
        break
    consumer.close()

except KafkaError as e:
    print(f"Failed to connect to Kafka broker: {e}")

This is the actual exception, i tried using bootstrap server LB FQDN and each of the 3 brokers LB FQDNs and no luck :(

Failed to connect to Kafka broker: NoBrokersAvailable
pods are healthy and services and user are available

kubectl get pods -n strimzi-kafka
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-cluster-entity-operator-6f4cc9b654-frzsw   2/2     Running   0          53m
my-cluster-kafka-broker-0                     1/1     Running   0          16m
my-cluster-kafka-broker-1                     1/1     Running   0          15m
my-cluster-kafka-broker-2                     1/1     Running   0          16m
my-cluster-kraft-controller-3                 1/1     Running   0          60m
my-cluster-kraft-controller-4                 1/1     Running   0          61m
my-cluster-kraft-controller-5                 1/1     Running   0          60m
strimzi-cluster-operator-6f9fbb4c75-twx8p     1/1     Running   0          75m

kubectl get services -n strimzi-kafka
NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                   PORT(S)                               AGE
my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap         ClusterIP      10.100.234.142   <none>                                                                        9091/TCP,9093/TCP                     15d
my-cluster-kafka-broker-plain-0    LoadBalancer   10.100.193.37    awslbfqdn9092:31351/TCP                        17m
my-cluster-kafka-broker-plain-1    LoadBalancer   10.100.234.209   awslbfqdn9092:31518/TCP                        17m
my-cluster-kafka-broker-plain-2    LoadBalancer   10.100.233.6     awslbfqdn9092:31231/TCP                        17m
my-cluster-kafka-brokers           ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                        9090/TCP,9091/TCP,8443/TCP,9093/TCP   15d
my-cluster-kafka-plain-bootstrap   LoadBalancer   10.100.13.61     awslbfqdn9092:31631/TCP                        17m

kubectl get kafkausers -n strimzi-kafka
NAME    CLUSTER      AUTHENTICATION   AUTHORIZATION   READY
flink   my-cluster   scram-sha-512    simple          True


Without full logs, it is always only guessing. But your Strimzi configuration is not really correct. You do not have enabled authentication, so you will sooner or later fail because the authorization will not allow you to do anything.

@Jakub but i do have authorization enabled at the cluster level as simple. are you saying I also need to enable authentication at the cluster level? I have authentication set at the user level. Also, just a side note that if i comment out all user related parameters from my python script the connection works. This leads me to believe theres something left to enable either at the cluster level or user level for user-based auth to work properly.

Yes, you have authorization  enabled. But authorization needs authentication to work properly. You should check the Strimzi docs or the GitHub examples to see how to enable authentication. It needs to be done in the listener section.

@Jakub I added authentication to my kafka resource config right under listeners but still getting the same error when trying to authenticate with my user.
spec:
kafka:
version: 3.8.0
metadataVersion: 3.8-IV0
authorization:
type: simple
listeners:
- name: plain
port: 9092
type: loadbalancer
tls: false
- name: tls
port: 9093
type: internal
tls: true
authentication:
type: scram-sha-512
I tried like this as well as directly under the port 9092 section, and still same behavior

Do you have any suggestions as to where i can find the logs on the cluster side? I dont see any activity at the pod level logs for neither the brokers or bootstrap pod

actually i changed it like this and i am getting something now! although the log is too long to put here. but my updated yaml looks like this now.
spec:
kafka:
version: 3.8.0
metadataVersion: 3.8-IV0
listeners:
- name: plain
port: 9092
type: loadbalancer
tls: false
authentication:
type: scram-sha-512
authorization:
type: simple
